# Python Interpolate Txt

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

Boa noite,
Recentemente comecei a programa em python por conta de um eletiva que tenho na universidade, mas meus conhecimentos ainda são mínimos.
Meu professor deu um trabalho para fazer onde devo criar um código que leia uma tabela Precos.txt desse jeito:

```
1,  69.00
2,  69.00
3,  69.00
4,  69.00
5,  69.00
6,  69.00
7,  69.00
8,  79.00
9,  56.51
10, 56.51
```

Onde a primeira coluna representa alguns dias do mês e a segunda coluna representa os preços.
Até onde eu consegui aprender, sei que posso fazer essa leitura com esses comandos:

```
precos = sp.loadtxt("Precos.txt", delimiter=",")
precos = np.genfromtxt('Precos.txt', delimiter=',')
x, y = np.loadtxt("Precos.txt", delimiter=",", unpack=True)
```

Após ler a tabela, o programa deve plotar um grafico, oque eu tambem consegui fazer sem nenhum tipo de problema:

```
plt.plot(x,y)
```

Meu problema começa agora. Meu professor quer q eu faça uma interpolação, e sugeriu usar `sp.interpolate.interp1d(x,y)` para gerar outro gráfico. Mas o programa não quer rodar.

Alguém poderia me ajudar? Existe alguem meio mais eficiente para fazer isso? Ou algo mais "profissional", visto que o ideal seria eu ler um arquivo CSV ao invés de um TXT.

Grato desde já

----EDIT----
Programa quase pronto, mas travei no erro:

> ValueError: A value in x_new is above the interpolation range.

```
import scipy as sp
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import interpolate

## Importando os dados numa matriz Nx2

M = sp.loadtxt('Precos.txt', delimiter=',')

## Construindo os vetores X e Y

x=np.zeros(len(M))
y=np.zeros(len(M))
for i in range(len(M)):
    x[i] = M[i][0]
    y[i] = M[i][1]

##Plotando grafico

plt.plot(x,y)
plt.title("Fone de Ouvido JBL com Microfone T100A - Fevereiro 2017")
plt.xlabel("Dia")
plt.ylabel("Preco em R$")

##Interpolação

F = sp.interpolate.interp1d(x,y)
xn = sp.arange(0,9,0.1)
yn = F(xn)
plt.plot(x, y, 'o', xn, yn, '-')
plt.show()
```

No caso dessa parte da Interpolação, foi meu professor que falou para eu usar assim. Mas não está adiantando muito.

Comment: Você já abriu um arquivo CSV comum editor de textos?

Não existe nada mais "profissional" num arquivo CSV do que num TXT - esse seu TXT aliás, esta estruturado como um CSV.

Comment: Sim sim..me expressei mal.

Answer (score 2):

Ficou um pouco vago na parte

> Mas o programa não quer rodar

Rodei aqui o seu programa sem grandes dificuldades, você sabe o que a função `interp1d` faz? por default ele faz uma interpolação linear com os seus dados de entrada `x e y`, ele retorna uma função na qual pode ser usado para encontrar qual é o valor interpolado de um dado ponto específico.

código:

```
from scipy import interpolate
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


x, y = np.loadtxt("Precos.txt", delimiter=",", unpack=True)
interpolado = interpolate.interp1d(x,y);
plt.plot(np.linspace(1, 10, 10),interpolado(np.linspace(1, 10, 10)))
plt.show()
```

Repara na linha `plt.plot(np.linspace(1, 10, 10),interpolado(np.linspace(1, 10, 10)))`  estou falando para plotar o retorno da função linearmente interpolado dos pontos entre 1 até 10, isso me retorna o seguinte plot:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E se eu quiser saber como seria o retorno da função de 20 pontos entre 1 e 10? `plt.plot(np.linspace(1, 10, 20),interpolado(np.linspace(1, 10, 20)))`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Edit**

Sobre o seu Edit

Rode com a seguinte linha `xn = sp.arange(1,10,0.1)` para interpolar de 1 até 10 espaçado linearmente por 0.1, o gráfico vai ser:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Você não pode achar a interpolação para valores acima 10, seus dados de entrada vão de 1 até 10, não importa a quantidade de valores interpolados que você encontre desde que eles estejam no intervalo de entrada dos dados.

Comment: Entendi...Eu tentei mudar o intervalo de 1 a 10 para 1 a 20, e o programa retornou "ValueError: A value in x_new is above the interpolation range." Saberia me explicar o motivo? No ultima versão desse programa eu já tinha esbarrado nesse erro, e até agora não consegui sair dele.

Comment: o seu problema é o `sp.arange(0,9,0.1)` o que vc espera dele ?